# pass two difference arrays for same array

Tags: pascal

I was trying to use same printing procedure for two types of arrays(1st arry length was 10, 2nd array length was 15).

I could not find any solution over internet. Did any one have any solution for this problem.

this is the Two arrays

```
program pp1;
const 
  m=10;
  n=15;
type
  matrix1=array[1..m] of integer;
  matrix2=array[1..n] of integer;
var
m1:matrix1;
m2:matrix2;
```

this is the method which it tried. in method 'x' mens the length of the array.

```
procedure writeMatrix(var data: array of integer ;x:integer);
var
  j:integer;
begin
   for j:=1 to x do
   begin
     write(data[j]:3);
   end;

end;
```

my main method

```
    begin
    writeMatrix(m1,10);
    writeMatrix(m2,10);
    end.
```

How can i use the same this writeMatrix method to print both of the arrays.. Is there any stranded way to do it.

Comment: What it's exactly the problem you have? the compiler complains about something or the output isn't what you expect? I ask because the  `writeMatrix()` implementation is fine, just make sure to fill the matrix first. And also, when you call `writeMatrix(a,7);` a isn't declared at least in this post, that should give you a compilation error.

Comment: The code of writeMatrix that you have provided is correct. Please, specify what exactly you wish to acheive and what error you have. Also consider using `Length`, `High` and `Low` functions to know the length of an array and high/low memebers' indexes respectively.

Comment: i have edited the main method like this its not working

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment before, your implementation is fine, but you have to put something in your matrix before printing it, or you will get a bunch of zeroes in the screen (in the best).

Try this:

```
program pp1;
const 
  m=10;
  n=15;
type
  matrix1=array[1..m] of integer;
  matrix2=array[1..n] of integer;
var
m1:matrix1;
m2:matrix2;

procedure fillMatrix(var data:array of integer; x:integer);
var
j:integer;
begin
for j:= 1 to x do begin
  data[j]:=j;
end;
end;


procedure writeMatrix(var data: array of integer; x:integer);
var
  j:integer;
begin
   for j:=1 to x do
   begin
     write(data[j]:3);
   end;    
end;

begin
  fillMatrix(m1,10);
  fillMatrix(m2,10);
  writeMatrix(m1,10);
  writeMatrix(m2,10);
  readln;
  readln;
end.
```

Hint: consider avoid using global variables, `m1` and `m2` in this case should be declared in the main program.

Comment: i tried like this.
it says ' Invalid function arguments ' from the first line of main method. fillMatrix(m1,10);

Comment: The problem now it's that `fillmatrix()` expects and `array of integer` parameter but we are sending `matrix1` and `matrix2` type arguments.
declare `m1` as  `array [1..m] of integer` and `m2` as `array [1..n] of integer`so you won't be using types `matrix1` and `matrix2`. I guess This types make coding "more generics" processes harder.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i use the same this writeMatrix method to print both of the arrays.. Is there any stranded way to do it.

Yes, there is a standard way to this. It is called *conformant-array parameters*. It is standardized in (level 1) of the [ISO standard 7185](http://www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#6.6.3.7%20Conformant%20array%20parameters) (Standard “Unextended” Pascal). It looks like this:

```pascal
procedure print(protected matrix: array[
        columnMinimum..columnMaximum: integer;
        rowMinimum..rowMaximum: integer
    ] of integer);
const
    totalWidth = 6;
var
    x: type of columnMinimum;
    y: type of rowMinimum;
begin
    for y := rowMinimum to rowMaximum do
    begin
        for x := columnMinimum to columnMaximum do
        begin
            write(matrix[x, y]:totalWidth);
        end;
        writeLn;
    end;
end;
```

It’s as if there were additional `const` values, but they are dynamic depending on the passed `matrix`. This code furthermore uses type inquiries (`type of …`) and the `protected` modifier, both defined in ISO 10206 (Extended Pascal) which builds on top of ISO 7185. In EP you could and would also consider schemata to pass such data as parameters.